# GPU code gives different time when run from VS2008 and when running only .exe

Tags: windows, cuda, gpgpu, nvidia

I have cuda events in my code to record the time of execution. When I click "Start Debuggin" from VS 2008, the timer gives a value of 1.5 seconds. However, when I run the program from .exe file, it gives time of .4 seconds. Why this difference?

Comment: Are you running your CUDA code on the same GPU board this is also handling your display ?

Comment: OK - if that GPU is also handling your display then obviously there is going to be some contention between running your CUDA code and screen updates.

Comment: @PaulR What do u mean by GPU handling display

Comment: Your GPU is on your video board. There is one bus between your PC and the video board. Screen updates go via this bus. GPU kernels and data go via this same bus. The GPU itself is used for both screen drawing and running CUDA code.

Comment: @PaulR which is really fun when you trick the debugger into setting a breakpoint on the same GPU that's handling the display...

Comment: @David Lively: indeed - I think that's *one* reason why nVidia recommend using two GPU boards for serious CUDA development. ;-)

Comment: @PaulR in their defense, I had to edit the Parallel NSight binaries in a hex editor to get it to work!

Comment: @David Lively: cool - I prefer Mac OS X or Linux for CUDA development (or anything else for that matter), but I have to admit I'm a little jealous that Windows users have GUI debugging for CUDA.

Comment: @PaulR: can u do debug using 1 gpu

Comment: Ask @David - he knows more about CUDA debugging on Windows - I debug via the command line on Linux and Mac OS X.

Comment: @programmer not in the traditional sense (watch, breakpoints, etc). Tools like Pix help a lot, but aren't perfect. Some guys color output pixels to indicate whether a condition is true, variable value, etc. Its primitive but useful. I'd recommend getting a second video card if you're going to be doing this a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no inherent reason that running attached to the debugger should introduce a performance difference, other than (just a few possibilities):

Do you have any conditional breakpoints set? Depending on the condition, these can have a dramatic impact on execution time.

Are you explicitly writing large amounts of data to the `Debug` or `Trace` listeners? (Edit: that's relevant for C#, probably not for C++.)

Is the EXE compiled in Release mode? By default, the Release config turns on optimizations that aren't present when building in Debug mode.

Is your timing code *really* only timing the relevant section? If you're starting the timer at the start of program execution instead of around the GPU calls that you're really interested in, you may be accidentally timing some startup tasks that are tied to running with the debugger that won't be active in a standalone app.